# jQuery .removeClass() not working

Tags: jquery

I have this situation a grid of divs with class of `person-s4` with a series of  div in it.

```
<div class="person-s4">
  <div class="is-closed"> <!--THIS IS DISPLAY:NONE -->
    <img src="assets/img/close.svg" class="close-btn">
   </div> 
  <div class="img-person-s4">
   <img src="assets/img/people/nb.png" class="small">
   <img src="assets/img/people/#" class="big"> <!--THIS IS DISPLAY:NONE -->
  </div>
  <div class="initials-person-s4">
    <h2>BLA BLA BLA</h2>
    <p class="initial1">N</p>
    <p class="initial2">B</p>
    <h3 class="person-role">BLA BLA BLA</h3> 
    <p class="bio">#</p>
    <h4 class="link">#</h4>
  </div>
```

I wrote some code in order to expand them on click

```
function personOpen() {
  $('.person-s4').click(function personBig() {

    $(this).addClass('is-open');

  });
}
```

Now, I want to remove the class `is-open` by clicking on the `close-btn`, I wrote this code but doesn't work.

```
function personClose() {
   $('.close-btn').click(function personSmall() {

     $('.person-s4').removeClass('is-open');

   });
}
```

There is anything that prevent the `.removeClass()` function to work?

I'm not creating DOM elements, I am just showing them.

Comment: is the add class working?

Comment: How are the `personOpen()` and `personClose()` functions being called?

Comment: @j08691 i've got a few left ;)

Comment: @j08691 Where is he creating elements dynamically?

Comment: What's the purpose of the `personBig` and `personSmall` function names?

Comment: @Barmar Change some CSS to open a dialog

Comment: @j08691 Where do you see that? He's not binding to the dynamic classes `is-open` and `is-closed`, he's binding to the static classes `person-s4` and `close-btn`.

Comment: @NicolaBertelloni The scope of the name in a named function expression is just the body of the function. How can those function names be used in a dialog?

Comment: @j08691 I'm not creating anything I'm just displaying or not some div

Comment: @NicolaBertelloni I wasn't asking the purpose of the classes, I was asking why you have names after the `function` keyword.

Comment: @Barmar just to help me debugging the code avoiding anonymus functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to add Event listeners inside a named function like that unless you really want to control when the event listeners get added. Change your code to:

```
$(function() {
  $('.person-s4').click(function() {

    $(this).addClass('is-open');

  });
});
```

and

```
$(function() {
   $('.close-btn').click(function() {

     $('.person-s4').removeClass('is-open');

   });
});
```

This way the event listeners are added once the DOM is completely loaded. And you don't have to specifically call the functions to add the event listeners.

EDIT: Sorry I copied your original code and didn't notice you had named the click function handlers. You don't do that either.

you had

```
 $('.person-s4').click(function personBig(){ ... });
```

that won't work the function should be an anonymous function.

```
$('.person-s4').click(function(){ ... });
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the structure of your DOM is not correct. You first need to create a container div that wraps your hidden contents. Also, you don't need to add or remove class. A simple toggle would do the job.

```
<div class="person-s4">Click
  <div class="is-closed"> <!--THIS IS DISPLAY:NONE -->
      <img src="assets/img/close.svg" class="close-btn">X</img>    
  <div class="img-person-s4">
   <img src="assets/img/people/nb.png" class="small">
   <img src="assets/img/people/#" class="big"> <!--THIS IS DISPLAY:NONE -->
  </div>
  <div class="initials-person-s4">
    <h2>BLA BLA BLA</h2>
    <p class="initial1">N</p>
    <p class="initial2">B</p>
    <h3 class="person-role">BLA BLA BLA</h3> 
    <p class="bio">#</p>
    <h4 class="link">#</h4>
  </div>
       </div>

$('.person-s4, .close-btn').click(function () {
    $(this).find(".is-closed").toggle("is-open");
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/njzatgku/

UPDATE : To toggle only the elements with `<!-- THIS IS DISPLAY:NONE -->` in the question.

http://jsfiddle.net/njzatgku/2/

Comment: So, the problem is that the "close button" have to be outside of the wrap? Because my intent is to hide and show only a couple objects, the main part is change the CSS of the others

Comment: If you wish to only toggle the elements mentioned in the question, refer to the updated fiddle.