# jQuery .removeClass Not Working

Tags: jquery

This probably won't be very hard for more experienced jQuery users, but I've been stumped. I have sets of divs on a page that are related. #vendor-1 & #vendor-1-content, #vendor-2 & #vendor-2-content, etc.

When the user clicks on #vendor-1, it add the class .is-visible to the #vendor-1-content. They can then click an "x" that will "close" the content by removing the .is-visible class. This is my code which works fine for just one div:

```
$('#vendor-1').click(function(){
  $('#vendor-1-content').addClass('is-visible');
});

$('#close').click(function(){
  $('.vendor-content').removeClass('is-visible');
});
```

I added the following code so that whichever id the user clicks, the corresponding content id gets the class .is-visible. The issue is that the #close portion only works on vendor-1-content. All of the other divs open properly, but won't close when clicked.

```
$(function (){
  $('[id^=vendor-]').click(function (){
    var num = this.id.split('vendor-')[1];
    var vendorId = '#vendor-' + num + '-content';

    $(vendorId).addClass('is-visible');

    $('#close').click(function() {
      $(vendorId).removeClass('is-visible');
    });
  });
});
```

What am I doing wrong in order to make the .is-visible be removed from the content class?

My html looks like this for each:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 vendor-card" id="vendor-1">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=28&bg=0099ff&txtclr=ffffff&txt=300%C3%97300&w=300&h=300&fm=png" alt="">
    <div class="vendor-info">
      <h3>Vendor Name</h3>
      <p>Short Vendor Description</p>
    </div>
  </div>

<div class="vendor-content" id="vendor-1-content">
<div>
  <h2>Vendor title here</h2>
  <em>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt, ullam.</em>
  <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium officia, fugit recusandae ipsa, quia velit nulla adipisci? Consequuntur aspernatur at, eaque hic repellendus sit dicta consequatur quae, ut harum ipsam molestias maxime non nisi reiciendis eligendi! Doloremque quia pariatur harum ea amet quibusdam quisquam, quae, temporibus dolores porro doloribus. 
  </p>
</div>
<a href="#0" class="close-content cd-img-replace" id="close">close</a>
</div>
```

Here is a codepen example of the code: http://codepen.io/Tambe257/pen/mPaZvw

Comment: please also post your HTML, you can use the SO snippets also.

Comment: @imvain2 See the edit - Thanks

Comment: This is the repeated question on stack overflow : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33487300/jquery-removeclass-not-working?rq=1

Comment: Thank you for finding that. I searched before posting, but I didn't see that one! This solution was a little different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this example:

```js
$(document).on('click', '[id^=vendor-]:not(.content)', function() {
  $('.content').removeClass('is-visible');
  $('[id="vendor-' + $(this).attr('id').split('-')[1] + '-content"]').addClass('is-visible');
});

$(document).on('click', '.closeContent', function(e) {
  console.log($(this).closest('.content').attr('id'));
  $(this).closest('.content').removeClass('is-visible');
});
```

```css
.content:not(.is-visible) { display:none }
.content {
   padding:5px;
   bacground-color:#e1e1e1;
   border:1px solid #d8d8d8;
}
.closeContent { cursor:pointer;color:red;margin-left:10px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="vendor-1">Vendor #1</div>
<div id="vendor-2">Vendor #2</div>
<div id="vendor-3">Vendor #3</div>
<div id="vendor-1-content" class="content"><span>Vendor #1 content</span><span class="closeContent">x</span></div>
<div id="vendor-2-content" class="content"><span>Vendor #2 content</span><span class="closeContent">x</span></div>
<div id="vendor-3-content" class="content"><span>Vendor #3 content</span><span class="closeContent">x</span></div>
```

Comment: It looks like your solution changes between the different Vendors, but it doesn't have a "close" button that completely removes the visible section. See my codepen above for what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Check my updated answer (included an 'x' button for closing each content)

Answer (score 1):

I changed a little your logic, check this out:

```
  <a class="vendor-click" data-id="1" href="javascript:void(0)">Vendor 1</a>
  <a class="vendor-click" data-id="2" href="javascript:void(0)">Vendor 2</a>
  <a class="vendor-click" data-id="3" href="javascript:void(0)">Vendor 3</a>
  <br/>
  <div id="vendor-content-1" class="vendor-content">content 1</div>
  <div id="vendor-content-2" class="vendor-content">content 2</div>
  <div id="vendor-content-3" class="vendor-content">content 3</div>
  <br/>
  <br/>

  <a id="close" data-id="1" href="javascript:void(0)">Close</a>
```

and the JS:

```
  $(".vendor-content").hide();

  $("#close").on("click", function() {
    $(".vendor-content").hide();
  });

  $(".vendor-click").on("click", function() {
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    $(".vendor-content").hide();
    $("#vendor-content-" + id).show();
  });
```

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/o9YFZ1KUvcVzGAvjn21L